# iOS NSURLConnection incorrect call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

My program register users through URL-requests, but before registration there is existence userlogin or his e-mail  checking in remote database. If this data not exist program should add user data in database or (if user or e-mail exist) program should return error.

I wrote this code:

```
 - (IBAction)buttonRegister:(id)sender {
    NSString *getDataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://*********/********.php?chklogin=%@&chkemail=%@",login.text,email.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection)
       urlDataCheckUser = [NSMutableData data];
    else NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
    }

  - (void) msgtitle: (NSString*) title msgtext: (NSString*) msg
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
       [urlDataCheckUser appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
       NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlDataCheckUser encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"])
       {
           [self msgtitle:@"Error" msgtext:@"E-mail or Login already use!"];
       }
       if ([strResult isEqualToString:@""])
       {
           NSString *getDataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://**********/**********.php?reglogin=%@&regemail=%@&regpass=%@",login.text,email.text,password.text];
           NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

           NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

           NSURLConnection *conn =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
           theRequest = nil;
           if (conn)
           {
               [self msgtitle:@"Success!" msgtext:@"Please login"];
           }

           UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
           UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
           [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
       }
    }

    - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
    {
       return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
    {
       [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
       [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
```

It is work, but i get message about successful registration  more then once.

What is wrong?

Comment: Where is your successful registration message? And how many times you calling `buttonRegister` method?

Comment: [self msgtitle:@"Success!" msgtext:@"Please login"]; - this is message about successful registration; I call buttonRegister method once and I'm get more then one message about successful registration.